# How to pass data through GET method in PHP

Tags: php, content-management-system

I have created a page where admins of a site can see and edit their menu navigation items.. As you can see in this image:

[image: print screen one]

So each menu item has two links next to it.. One for deleting the menu item and the other one for updating it.

Basically what I did for updating the menu item is grabbing the id of that item and redirect it to another page called `itemedit.php` like this:

```
<a title='Edit' href='itemedit.php?i=$i'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a>
```

And in the page `itemedit.php` I did this:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['i'])){
    $i = $_GET['i'];
    $e = // The name that user entered
    $editItem = new Menus();

    if(isset($_POST['yes'])){
        $editItem->EditMenuItem($i,$e);
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=menus.php">';   
        exit; 
    }
    if(isset($_POST['no'])){
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=menus.php">';    
        exit; 
    }

    echo "
<section class='content' style='text-align:center;'>
                <form action='' method='POST'>
                    <h5><strong> 
                        Are you sure you want to edit the selected item ?</br></br>
                    </strong></h5>   
                    <p> 
                        <button name='yes' type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Yes</button>
                        <button name='no' type='submit' class='btn'>No</button>
                    </p> 
                </form> 
            </section>";
```

So if an admin clicked on "YES" , It should call the `Menus` class which goes like this:

*I have skipped writing down the db connection and extra information in this class*

```
<?php
class Menus{
    public function EditMenuItem($i,$e)
        {
            if(!empty($i))
            {
                $adm = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE menu_nav SET menu_link_$i =                  $e");
                $adm->bindParam(1,$i);
                $adm->execute();
            }
            else
            {
                header("Location: php/includes/errors/012.php");
                exit();
            }
        }
}
?>
```

Now the problem is I don't know how can I pass the data through the **$e** variable which contains the new edition of that menu item.

And because I have used a hyperlink rather than an input to redirect my page to `itemedit.php`, I cant pass a name attribute. So is there any way or solution to pass this data correctly in `itemedit.php` or no ?

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['i'])){
    $i = $_GET['i'];
    $e = // The name that user entered
    $editItem = new Menus();
```

Comment: Appending the name with javascript to the link (on click event in link) is a valid option for you? If so i will post an example as answer

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data in the header of the get request.

Have a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php